# What would this projection return?

Tags: sql, projection, relational-algebra

I'm new to sql, if I run this projection on a table, would it return nothing or an error of this projection is not allowed (syntax)? I put all infos of the table and the projection in this picture below to make it easier to read :)

[image: my table and projection]

Comment: SQL & relational algebra are two different things. Also, what *reference* were you given for (your version of) 'relational algebra'? Whate *definition* were you given for projection? PS Please use text not images whenever possible, like for this question. (You can google 'unicode pi' etc if you want a symbol.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relational algebra, your set difference would yield an error because the two sets are not union-compatible:

> For set union and set difference, the two relations involved must be union-compatible—that is, the two relations must have the same set of attributes. [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Set_operators)

In SQL, the set difference would work, because union compatibility is understood in a more lenient way, i.e. the tuple degrees and data types must match, but not the names. So this is valid SQL:

```sql
SELECT X FROM A
EXCEPT
SELECT Z FROM A
```

The result would be a table with a single column named `X`

However, even in SQL, you couldn't project `Y` from the set difference, so π<sub>Y</sub> is not possible, neither in SQL nor in relational algebra. This would be invalid SQL:

```sql
SELECT Y -- Y is not defined here, only X
FROM (
  SELECT X FROM A
  EXCEPT
  SELECT Z FROM A
)
```